# How can I Apply title/ tooltip / popover on options of select by using ng-option/ ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to dynamically apply popover on options of select tag **not on select tag but on options** here is my code

You can further refer to this code in which I need to apply tooltip

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedCategory2" id="category" style="width:280px;" name="category" ng-change="onselectedchange2(selectedCategory2,DomainLoginId,selectedCategory3)" popover="{{allow}}" popover-trigger="mouseenter" popover-placement="right required>
    <option ng-repeat=" item in groupData" value="{{item.sso_access_type}}" title="{{allow}}">{{item.sso_access_type}}</option>
</select>
```

As per this code, the output which I got in Firefox is

```
<option ng-repeat=" item in groupData" value="S_Adv-Type6" title="Read-Only Access, S Budgets , S Billing" class="ng-binding ng-scope">S_Adv-Type6</option>

<option ng-repeat=" item in groupData" value="S_Adv-Type6" title="Read-Only Access, S Budgets , S Billing" class="ng-binding ng-scope">S_Adv-Type6</option>
```

You can see the title for both option become same I want it to be different as in controller.

below is my image link I want like this [[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P32Zl.jpg): https://i.stack.imgur.com/P32Zl.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P32Zl.jpg)

Comment: You have used the value `{{ allow }}` as title for all options, shouldn't that be `{{ item.someUniqueProperty }}` ?

Comment: No the description is coming from some other place. so I have to use {{allow}} only. this project is developed and I have to make changes so I can't do what you are saying.

Comment: Yes but the name of the variable is the same for all options - `allow`, which will resolve to the same value. You need to have different values for the title.

Comment: But how can I have Different values for {{allow}} any suggestion?    Like if I use some different value then also it's going to repeat. As we Have just one option tag.

Comment: If you can create a working code example and share maybe I can help. It is difficult to understand your expectation by looking at the current code.

Comment: [Github link](https://github.com/leocaseiro/angular-chosen/issues/224)    [code link(http://plnkr.co/edit/Gt6uF9QfulNp6UzpzOrG?p=preview)    you can refer git hub and my comment over there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set allow key in each item of your groupData

```
$scope.groupData = [
    {sso_access_type = 'one' , allow:'allowOne'},
    {sso_access_type = 'tow' , allow:'allowTow'}
];
```

and set option like this

```
<option ng-repeat=" item in groupData" value="{{item.sso_access_type}}" title="{{item.allow}}">{{item.sso_access_type}}</option>
```